# Cannot find either column "" or the user-defined function or aggregate "", or the name is ambiguous

Tags: xml, t-sql

I'm getting the above warning in some T-SQL I'm working on that uses an XML data type. The code runs as expected, but the warning is annoying, as it shows up in the editor and when I build my database project in VS2010. Here's a sample:

```
DECLARE @ID TABLE (ID INT)

INSERT @ID VALUES(1)
INSERT @ID VALUES(2)
INSERT @ID VALUES(3)

DECLARE @IDXml XML
SET @IDXml = (
    SELECT ID FROM @ID FOR XML RAW('IDFilter')
)

-- Cannot find either column "item" or the user-defined function or aggregate
-- "item.value", or the name is ambiguous.
SELECT SomeID = item.value('@ID', 'INT')
FROM @IDXml.nodes('/IDFilter') AS T(item)
```

Is the warning normal, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you get the same warning if you include the table name ("T")?  SELECT SomeID = T.item.value('@ID', 'INT')

Comment: I see the same as you when I paste it into SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. Looks like a bug. Probably worth reporting on the Microsoft Connect site.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add:

```
SET 'ANSI_PADDING' ON
```